# Custom unsaved form warning in Safari appears twice

Tags: javascript, forms, safari, webkit, onbeforeunload

I created a warning for the unsaved exit from a page with **beforeunload** event.

This works so far, but in Safari the default warning is sometimes added.

As far as I can see it only happens when you edit at least two input fields, but not when you edit a **textarea, selects or content editable**.

But especially on **textfield**s the warning would be most important.

Is there a way to listen for the warning in js and then not play my own **beforeunload** event? Or can I deactivate the Safari warning permanently via js? Thank you

Comment: I don't think there is a way to make Safari cooperate. I'd keep the inputs outside the form and add their values before submitting.

Comment: by in-house warning, do you mean safari`s own default warning??

Comment: @Abilogos exactly, greetings from Germany ;)